# Referencing `self` from within a VTCompressionOutputCallback

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, video-toolbox

I'm currently trying to use VideoToolbox to encode video data from an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`, but I'm having an issue referencing `self` from within the `VTCompressionOutputCallback`.

My code is as follows:

```
...

var sessionRef: VTCompressionSession?

let outputCallback: VTCompressionOutputCallback = { _, _, status, _, sampleBuffer in
    guard status == noErr, let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer else {
        return
    }

    debugPrint("[INFO]: outputCallback: sampleBuffer: \(sampleBuffer)")
}

let sessionErr = VTCompressionSessionCreate(allocator: nil,
                                            width: width,
                                            height: height,
                                            codecType: kCMVideoCodecType_H264,
                                            encoderSpecification: nil,
                                            imageBufferAttributes: nil,
                                            compressedDataAllocator: nil,
                                            outputCallback: outputCallback,
                                            refcon: nil,
                                            compressionSessionOut: UnsafeMutablePointer(&sessionRef))

...
```

That works fine, and the print outputs as expected, but as soon as I try and add a reference to `self` within the `VTCompressionOutputCallback`, it get a compiler error stating

`A C function pointer cannot be formed from a closure that captures context`

How can I use `self` from within the callback?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a solution.

The `VTCompressionSessionCreate` call has a parameter for `outputCallbackRefCon` which gets passed along to the `VTCompressionOutputCallback`.

By wrapping self in an `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` like so

```
let unmanagedSelf = UnsafeMutableRawPointer(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())
```

I was able to pass that value into the `VTCompressionSessionCreate` under the `refcon` parameter. Inside of the callback I was then able to do pull that value back out using

```
let scopedSelf = Unmanaged<ViewController>.fromOpaque(unmanagedSelf).takeUnretainedValue()
```

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `self` in using `passRetained()`, and consume it with `takeRetainedValue()`, so that `VTCompressionSessionCreate` has a strong reference keeping `self` alive? By passing unretained, it is possible that in a case with no strong references remaining to keep `self` alive, it can get deallocated before your callback is called. You would get a dangling pointer.